# Android Web App Image gallery using Hand gestures

Tags: javascript, android, css

I am looking for a way to create a Image GAllery for a web application for smartphone using CSS and Javascript but still using the same hand gestures that people find when using the the galley widget, the fling or swing.

Does anyone have any idea?

Comment: I found this link: http://www.webappers.com/2010/12/08/how-to-create-mobile-image-gallery-web-application/

Answer (score 0):

You will need to use the Gestures API to recognise different gestures from the user.

[Gestures](http://developer.android.com/resources/articles/gestures.html)